# virtually rotating the view with intrinsic and extrinsic parameter known

Tags: image-processing, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a top view using open cv?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3607/how-to-get-a-top-view-using-open-cv)

I have an image taken from an angle, at a height h from ground. I have all the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters, I need to get birds eye view from the image, How can i approach this ? My first approach was based on wrap perspective mapping but it somehow seems wrong cause i didn't find a way to use any camera parameters there. Correct me if I am wrong. Also the problem is that I need to use only one fixed camera to get a birds eye view.  Thank's in advance :)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/3607/1273 (or at least, the answer answers your question as well)

Comment: @penelope: It seems common for multiple people to ask the same question within a short time period.  I assume they're all taking the same class. :)

Comment: @endolith maybe, but that does not mean they shouldn't try to search through the site first. No offence to anybody :/